# Count number of results in a View

Tags: php, sql, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I need to count how many people belong in pre-defined groups (this is easy to do in SQL using the SELECT COUNT statement). My Views query runs fine and displays the actual data in my table, but I simply need to know how many results it found.

However there doesn't seem to be a COUNT option in views. I am guessing I am going to have to use some sort of views hook, and then stick the result in the table.

Here's a quick example of what i'm trying to achieve:

```
My Table
----------------------
Group A | 20 people
Group B | 63 people
```

and so on.

(I've tried using the Views_Calc module, but I get errors because it is not quite stable yet.)

Anybody know of an easy way to count results in Views?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good d.o thread about it:
http://drupal.org/node/131031

Although if you JUST need the count and not the other things Views offers (field formatting & ordering, etc), why not just code up the proper SELECT COUNT statement and call it a day?

(If you DO in fact need those other pieces Views offers, there are many examples on that thread above.)

Comment: a lot of the posts are about placing the code in the footer. I need the count to be displayed in the table row. or did i miss something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using the [Views Group By module](http://drupal.org/project/views_groupby) for this type of functionality.

I'm actually working on adding other aggregate functions (`MIN`, `MAX`, etc.) into it but since you only need the `COUNT` function, I think it's a pretty good option.

All you have to do (after installing and enabling the module), in the View that you are interested:

1. Add fields for the criteria that you want to `GROUP BY`.
2. Add the SQL Aggregation field as the last field (or swap it into the last).
3. Choose the fields (you can select multiple fields) `Fields to Group On`.
4. `SQL Aggregation Function` should be set to `Count`.
5. Fields to `Aggregate with the SQL function` set to a field that you are not grouping by. (This will be added into the `COUNT` function like `COUNT(<this field>)` in SQL)
6. The rest is up to you and click `Update`.

You should have the `COUNT` output from the field that you selected to aggregate.

Comment: I've been trying out this module ... unfortunately I've only been able to get to display "uid: 1" for every person in the group (instead of an actual count or total). I am grouping on "group", aggregating with "uid" and sorting with "group". any ideas?

Comment: That's odd. If you are getting every person in the group, then I don't think you are grouping successfully. You might want to check the output SQL. Also, check that you are not sorting by a criteria (in the Sorting Criteria block) that is not in the group by.