# How to print count results from specific views in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I know that in Views Drupal 7 module I can print out the count results by adding "Global Result Summary" to header or footer.

But how to print only those count result on a block?

[views Global Result Sumary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N0Hi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Oh i got the answer from: [Drupal return number of results in a View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973975/drupal-return-number-of-results-in-a-view?rq=1)

```
$view = views_get_view('viewname');
$view->set_display('block_1');     
$view->render();   
print sizeof($view->result);
```

Thanks.